# How to increase the conversion of a reaction between an ammonium salt and ethylenediamine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

[image]
I've been trying this reaction in my lab and there is the formation of the substituted ethylene diamine but along with that, I am obtaining some amount of RCH2N(CH3)2. The reaction is done under solvent-free condition using only excess of ethylenediamine. After the reaction, it is washed with water and the compound is extracted with DCM. Can anyone suggest me a method to ensure complete conversion of the ammonium salt? Increasing reaction time or temperature isn't showing any effect.

Comment: You are asking your nucleophile to attack the most hindered site. My suggestion would be alter the leaving species by using something more hindered than trimethylamine. Can you use, say, pyrrolidine to form the intial amine, quaternise with ethyl iodide then react with ethylene diamine?

Comment: @Waylander Thank you for responding. Basically what you are saying is that I've to use more sterically hindered amine. I can try that but the problem is the R group here is ferrocene which is already quite bulky. So, the formation of RCH2N(CH3)2 might be inevitable. It's a good suggestion though. I can try it.

Comment: Can you do this a slightly different way? If you take the ferrocene dimethylamine (your undesired side product), oxidise to the N-oxide and then acylate you could do a Polonovski rearrangement to give the aldehyde. Reductive amination of this with mono-BOC ethylenediamine would give a much cleaner reaction.